# Django query using through model

Tags: django, django-models

```
a = models.ManyToManyField('self', through = 'x')
```

How to make a query on a by filtering through 'x'

Comment: Have you tried `x__`?

Comment: Yes I did...can you tell me the full query

Comment: can u give an query example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `symmetrical=False` when creating the field. In `Django 1.7` if you try your definition you will get an error similar to this:

```
CommandError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
myapp.MyModel.a: (fields.E332) Many-to-many fields with intermediate tables must not be symmetrical.
```

so change the field to

```
a = models.ManyToManyField('self', through = 'x', symmetrical = False)
```

Now it all depends on your `x` class. It have to define two foreignKey fields back to `yourModel`:

```
class x(models.Model):
    from_a = models.ForeignKey(myClass, related_name = 'from_a')
    to_a = models.ForeignKey(myClass, related_name = 'to_a')
    comment = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
```

Now you don't filter from `x` but from the reversed relations created by the FK's, i.e. something like this:

```
myClass.objects.filter(from_a__comment='something')
```

or from an instance perspective:

```
my_instance.a.filter(from_a__comments='something')
```

A great article about the topic can be found here: [Self-referencing many-to-many through](https://charlesleifer.com/blog/self-referencing-many-many-through/)